# How can I make the last row in a grid view's colspan equal to the number of columns in the grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello I have a grid view i am creating and I want to have the last row of that grid view to have colspan equal to the total number of colums in the grid view.

How can I do this programatically in c#.

I tried to do :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
              e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count-1].ColumnSpan = e.Row.Cells.Count-1;
        }
}
```

.... but that didn't do it.

Here is a picture of what I am trying to do..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == dt.Rows.Count - 1) //dt=Datasource
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dt.Columns.Count; //your text have to be in cell[0]
            e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false; //make the other cells invisible
            e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
        }
    }
```